# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - How do I access previously paired device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm developing and Android app that connects to a device via Bluetooth Low Energy.

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to connect to a device I had previously connected do. In the phone's Bluetooth settings it shows the bluetooth device as "Paired" so I would like to connect to it from the app to 'talk' to it.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of bonded devices from BluetoothAdapter:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Then identify the device you are interested in and connect:

```
myBluetoothGatt = myBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, myGattCallback);
```